# How to make return type of function generic in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, class, generic-programming

### Intro

In my app, I have one **superclass called "ElementData"** and *several child classes that inherit from it.*

> Each child class has its own validateModel() method which returns
>   a different type, depending on the class - always in an Array.

**In other words:** the method returns different Types in every subclass.

### Example

**Class A:** `func validateModel() -> [String]`

**Class B:** `func validateModel() -> [Int]`

**Class C:** `func validateModel() -> [MyCustomEnum]`

As you can see, only the return values differ from each other.

**EDIT: Examples of validateModel() method:**

**Class A:**

```
func validateModel() -> [DefaultElementFields]{ // DefaultElementFields is an enum with the different view types of my collection view

        var checkResult: [DefaultElementFields] = []

        if name == "" {
            checkResult.append(.Name)
        }

        if Int(rewardedPoints) == nil {
            checkResult.append(.Points)
        }

        if description == "" {
            checkResult.append(.Description)
        }

        if selectedImage == nil {
            checkResult.append(.Image)
        }

        return checkResult
    }
```

**Class B:**

```
func validateModel() -> [Int] { // returns the index of the text field which is wrong
        var checkResult: [Int] = []

        let filledValues = codes.filter {
            $0 != ""
        }

        if filledValues.count == 0 { // if no values have been entered, all fields should be marked red.
            checkResult.append(-1)
            return checkResult
        }


        for (i, code) in codes.enumerated() {
            if code != "" && (code.count < 3 || code.count > 10 || code.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted) != nil){ // code must have more than 3 and less than 11 characters. No symbols are allowed.
                checkResult.append(i)
            }
        }



        return checkResult
    }
```

**EDIT: What the classes are for:**

The classes basically **store data** a user entered **into collection view cells**, e.g. text, numbers or dates. Each CollectionViewCellType has its own class. Due to **reuse behavior** of the collection view, it is necessary to store the entered values in a **model**.

The **model** also **takes care of the validation** and returns - depending on the cell - an array of values that tells the cell which fields should get a red border (be marked as invalid).

This can sometimes be an Enum, an Int or a String.

### What I would like to achieve

As you might imagine, it is quite annoying to have almost the same validationMethods in each **child-class** as it is necessary to **downcast** every time I want to use the method on one of the classes.

Therefore, I would like to keep the **return type open** i.e. don't specify a specific one in the parent class as the subclass should be able to return any type. Then, I would move the **validateModel()** method into the parent class and override the method in its subclasses.

I thought of a solution with **generics** (if it's possible).

### What I tried

**Here is my generic approach for the whole thing:**

```
class ElementData {

    func validateModel<T>() -> [T] {
        return [1] as! [T] // just a test return
    }

}
```

**And the call of the method:**

```
dataObject.validateModel() // dataObject inherits from ElementData -> has access to validateModel()
```

Unfortunately, it does not work and I get the following error:

> "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

### Summary:

- I have one **superclass** "ElementData" and several subclasses (classes that inherit)
- Each **subclass has a method validateModel()** in which the model is validated
- Only the **return types** of the validateModel() methods inside the subclasses **differ** - so I would like to put the method inside the parent class (ElementData) and just **override** it on the subclasses

**Is that possible, if so, how?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, show us at least two implementations of your validation method. There are two possibilities. Either use a protocol instead of a superclass, or make the whole class generic.

Comment: To infer the generic type, you would have to do something like `let array: [Int] = dataObject.validateModel()` to infer the type using the return value.

Comment: @Sulthan but then I still had to cast down each object in order to access the method and know what it returns, right? BTW: see edit

Comment: So far  I don't see anything in common inside your methods and I am not sure why do you even call the methods equally.

Comment: @Sulthan The code inside the methods is different in each class - but the basic function only differs in the return type. Now I have to switch on the type of my cell in order to know which elementDataClass it is. If I would have the validateModel method in the top class I could call it on every DataElementClass without casting it. I hope it’s more clear now :)

Comment: Side note: returning an array doesn't sound like model validation, to me. Either rename `validateModel()`, or change its behaviour.

Comment: @Alexander absolutely right. I think I should call it getInvalidFields() or something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible.

## What generics are for

Suppose you have this function:

```
func identity(_ value: Any) -> Any {
    return value
}
```

It doesn't actually work:

```
let i = 5
assert(identity(i) == i) // ❌ binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any' and 'Int'
```

`Any` causes type information to be lost. Even though we see that the type of the parameter and the return value will always be the same, we haven't expressed that to the type system. This is a perfect use-case for a generic type parameter. It allows us to express the relationships between the types of the parameter and the return value.

```
func identity<T>(_ value: T) -> T {
    return value
}

let i = 5
assert(identity(i) == i) // ✅
```

## What generics are not for

Looking back at your problem, you see that there are no type relationships here to be expressed.

- `ClassA.validateModel()` always returns `[String]`
- `ClassB.validateModel()` always returns `[Int]`
- `ClassC.validateModel()` always returns `[MyCustomEnum]`

That's not generic.

## How would it even work?

Suppose you had an object of type `ElementData`. That object could be an instance of `ElementData`, or of `ClassA`, or `ClassB`, or `ClassC`. Given that all four of these types are possible, and assuming there exists some concoction to do what you want, how would this code work?

```
let elementData = someElementData()
let validatedModel = elementData.validateModel() //  What type is `someValue` supposed to be?
```

Since we (nor the compiler) knows what concrete type the value of `elementData` will be (we only know that it's an `ElementData`, or one of its subclasses), how is the compiler supposed to determine the type of `validatedModel` ?

Furthermore, your code would be breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle. `ClassA` needs to support being substituted where `ElementData` is expected. One of the things that `ElementData.validateModel()`can do is return a `Something`. Thus, `ClassA.validateModel()` needs to either return a `Something`, or a subclass (strangely, it seems that only inheritence relationships work, not protocol subtype relationships. For example, returning `Int` where `Any` is expected doesn't work). Since `ClassA.validateModel()` returns `Array<String>`, and `Array` isn't a class (thus, can't have a superclass), there's no possible type `Something` that could be used to make the code not violate LSP and compile.

Here's an illustration of LSP, and how *Covariance* works in return types of overridden methods, and not in parameter types of overridden methods.

```
// https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html

class Animal {}
class Cat: Animal {}
    
class Person {
    func purchaseAnimal() -> Animal {
        return Animal()
    }
}

class CrazyCatLady: Person {
    // Totally legal. `Person` has to be able to return an `Animal`.
    // A `Cat` is an animal, so returning a `Cat` where an `Animal` is required is totally valid
    override func purchaseAnimal() -> Cat {
        return Cat()
    }

//  This method definition wouldn't be legal, because it violates the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP).
//  A `CrazyCatLady` needs to be able to stand in anywhere a `Person` can be used. One of the things a
//  `Person` can do is to `pet(animal: Animal)`. But a `CrazyCatLady` can't, because she can only pet cats.
//
//  If this were allowed to compile, this could would be undefined behaviour:
//
//      let person: Person = getAPerson()
//      let animal: Animal = getAnAnimal()
//      person.pet(animal)
//
//  override func pet(animal: Cat) { // ❌ method does not override any method from its superclass
//      
//  }
}
```

## One approach to a solution

First of all, we need to establish what's in common between these return types. If we could do that, then the compiler has an answer to the question of "what type should someModel be?" above.

There are two tools available:

1. Class inheritance (subclasses are subtypes of their superclasses)
2. Protocol conformance (protocol conforming types are subtypes of the protocols they conform to)

Both have advantages/disadvantages. Protocols force you in the painful road of dispair that is `associated-type`, whereas Classes are less flexible (since they can't be subclassed by enums or structs). In this case, the answer lies with what you want this code to do. Fundamentally, you're trying to hook this data up to a table cell. So make a protocol for that:

```
protocol CellViewDataSource {
    func populate(cellView: UICellView) {
        // adjust the cell as necessary.
    }
}
```

Now, update your methods to return this type:

```
class ElementData {
    func validateModel() -> CellViewDataSource {
        fatalError()
    }
}

class ClassA {
    func validateModel() -> CellViewDataSource {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

To implement these methods, you'll have to extend `Array` to conform to `CellViewDataSource`. However, that's a pretty terrible idea. I suggest instead that you create a new type (probably a `struct`) that stores the data you need.

```
struct ModelA {
    let name: String
    let points: Int
    let description: String
    let image: UIImage
}

extension ModelA: CellViewDataSource {
    func populate(cellView: UICellView) {
        // Populate the cell view with my `name`, `points`, `description` and `image`.
    }
}

class ElementData {
    func validateModel() -> CellViewDataSource {
        fatalError("Abstract method.")
    }
}

class ClassA {
    func validateModel() -> CellViewDataSource {
        return ModelA(
            name: "Bob Smith",
            points: 123,
            description: "A dummy model.",
            image: someImage()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you habe any other approach I could follow in order to avoid switching on my cell types and then casting down the dataObject? I am kind of lost because I don’t know how I could improve my classes/model...

Comment: @linus_hologram I'm working on it, but it's taking me a while to explain effectively

Comment: @linus_hologram Check now

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. So, the populate method returns a finished uiview for the cell? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: With my example, the TableViewDelegate dequeues a cell and passes in to the model, so that the model can populate in its data (by modifying the cell object, which is passed by reference). Returning the object in that case won't actually achieve anything. But the specifics aren't too important.  You just need to delegate the responsibility of populating the destination view (table cell or whatever).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196665/discussion-between-alexander-and-linus-hologram).

Comment: Hey Alexander, I am having another question regarding a class structure for my project. Would it be okay for you if I'd open up another chat-room?

Comment: sure, mention me in it and i'll get notified

Comment: I did that but in case you didn't get the notification here's the link: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199467/room-for-linus-hologram-and-alexander

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution is a protocol with associated types. You have to specify the return type as `typealias` in each subclass.

```
protocol Validatable {
    associatedtype ReturnType
    func validateModel() -> [ReturnType]
}

class ElementData {}

class SubClassA : ElementData, Validatable {
    typealias ReturnType = Int

    func validateModel() -> [Int] { return [12] }

}

class SubClassB : ElementData, Validatable {
    typealias ReturnType = String

    func validateModel() -> [String] { return ["Foo"] }
}
```

Now the compiler knows the different return type of all subclasses

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. But is there a way to move the validateModel() method into the parent class? And the subclasses only overrides it? Because the actual problem I have is that I would like to avoid downcasting a class in order to get access to validateModel()?

Comment: No, not with heterogeneous return types.

Comment: Nevermind! I haven’t tried it yet but I think your solution could work.

Comment: If I am trying to downcast my class to Validatable I get the following error: "Protocol 'Validatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

Another Error I get when I'm trying to use the function: "Member 'validateModel' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'Validatable'; use a generic constraint instead"


How can I access the functions I have specified inside of the Validatable protocol?

Comment: You are using `Validatable` as a type. That's not possible with a protocol and associated types. You can only constrain a type to the protocol.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Please search for *can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type*

Comment: I googled it a few times and read almost any article about it. But: I still don't get it - what is the problem with my protocol? Is there anything I could do?

Comment: I don't know what you are going to accomplish. My answer is a way to implement a method with the same signature but different return types